# Solve an ODE with Maple

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I am studying numerical solutions of a certain ODE using the program **Maple**. In order to better understand the software, I simplified my ODE to reach the following system
\begin{equation}
y'(x)x|\ln(x)| - 2y(x) = 0 \quad \text{on }[0,1/2],
\end{equation}
which can be solved analytically and gives the class of solution
$$y(x) = \frac{C}{|\ln(x)|^2},$$
for $C \in \mathbb R$.

Now, using Maple, I get essentially the same result:
[image]
However, the function given by the program is defined on $\mathbb R$ whereas I am only interested in what happens on a neighbourhood of $0$ (the choice of $1/2$ as an upper bound of the interval is arbitrary, any other value smaller than $1$ would be fine as well). Moreover, I cannot manipulate the function given by the program, e.g. when I evaluate it at a certain point it gives me this:
[image]

I tried numerous things to circumvent the difficulty but I couldn't figure out a way to solve it and neither have I found an answer online to my question. Any help would be great.

Comment: Why the down vote? I would be happy to add details if the question is unclear to anyone.

Comment: Your question is a Maple usage query and as such it's not "mathematics" in the context of this site. This is not a coding site. Mostly such kinds of coding/usage questions are closed by moderator votes. You could try stackoverflow or mapleprimes.com instead. But if you do then you should provide code-to-reproduce. Images are inadequate.

Comment: Okay I didn't know that. I thought this website was fine as the "Maple" tag has more that 5000 hits. I'll post it on these website then, thank you for your advice.

Comment: That was the official spiel. I'm happy to give your an answer, regardless. But wherever you post in future, it's far better etiquette to supply copy/paste'able 1D plaintext Maple code than images of Maple's marked up 2D Input. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the solving you had:

```
restart;
ODE := {diff(y(x),x)*x*abs(ln(x))-2*y(x)=0}:
Sol_ODE := dsolve(ODE):
eval_Sol_ODE := eval(y(x), Sol_ODE):
```

Your `eval_Sol_ODE` is an expression. You can *evaluate an expression at a point* by using the `eval` command. For example,

```
eval(eval_Sol_ODE, x=1/2);

    c__1/ln(2)^2

eval(eval_Sol_ODE, x=2/3);

    c__1/ln(2/3)^2
```

You could also construct a re-usable operator (procedure) from your expression. You could then *apply the operator to arguments*. For example,

```
func_eval_Sol_ODE := unapply(eval_Sol_ODE, x):

func_eval_Sol_ODE(1/2);

    c__1/ln(2)^2

func_eval_Sol_ODE(2/3);

    c__1/ln(2/3)^2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it's exactly what I needed!